# Table of TextInput in Kivy. How to acces each of TextInputs

Tags: python, kivy

I'm making an app where I need a table of `TextInput` that I will fill with some content. After it is done I click on the `Store` `Button` and then the content is printed by `id` or `coordinates` or any way that will let me to distinguish the`TextInputs`. I would like to avoid manually creating each `TextInput` and its `id` in `.kv` file. Is it possible in below code?

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'multisamples', '0')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
import weakref
from kivy.clock import Clock

kv = """

#:import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition
ScreenManager:
    transition: FadeTransition()
    ShipmentsScreen:

<TextInput@TextInput>
    size_hint_y: None
    height: 20

<Row>:
    cols: 3
    TextInput:
    TextInput:
    TextInput:

<Rows>:
    orientation: 'vertical' 

<ShipmentsScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Button:
            text: 'Store'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 20 
            on_press: rows.store()
        Rows:
            id: rows

"""

class Row(GridLayout):
    pass

class Rows(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Rows, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.fill)
        self._rows = {}

    def fill(self, dt):
        for i in range(30):
            row = Row()
            self.add_widget(row)
            self._rows["row"+str(i)] = weakref.ref(row)

    def store(self):
        #loop that will access each textinput and print its content
        print("textinput content by id or coordinates x, y")

class ShipmentsScreen(Screen):
    pass

sm = Builder.load_string(kv)

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: your code works for me. Code creates 30 rows with TextInput. I don't see the problem. Linux Mint / Python 3.7, PL: u mnie działa - kod tworzy mi 30 wierszy z  TextInput. Nie widzę gdzie jest problem.

Comment: Yes the code works but I need to create a function that will print text inputs in the loop in some order (for instance: `id` or `coordinates` so that will give me ability to store them to file or data base.

Comment: you keep rows in dictionary - so you have access to all rows. If you use list or `OrderDict` then it will keep order. As I remeber since Python 3.6 even normal dictionary should keep order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
def store(self):
    for id, row in self._rows.items():
        print(id)
        col = 0
        for ti in row().children:
            print('\tcol #', col, ti.text)
            col += 1
```

Just realized that the above code gets the column numbers reversed. This code gets it right:

```
def store(self):
    for id, row in self._rows.items():
        print(id)
        children = row().children
        col = len(children) - 1
        for ti in children:
            print('\tcol#', col, ti.text)
            col -= 1
```

Comment: That's exacly what I need.

Comment: The original code gets the column numbers backward. I added a corrected version of the code.

Comment: Yes I have noticed that but knew what's going on. Thanks for your patience. What we accuatly have got here is I think,  someting pretty similar to the recycleview.